# Show blue dots icon on current location Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm getting confused when my blue dot icon is dissapeared. The past is i can show the blue dot icon. But now it just zoom the camera on my current location without blue dot icon.

Here is my code:

```
private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, location.toString());
    double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 21));
  }
```

[image]

Comment: You probably need to update your marker on the location change... check the documentation on markers [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker).

Comment: You have to click the `MyLocation` button to show the blue dot.  You can enable it by calling `mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`, although it looks like you already have it enabled in your screenshot.

Answer (score 42):

You need to do as following:

```
GoogleMap myMap;
myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

You can get all sample project code on my github [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/GoogleMap-InfoWindow-android/tree/master) and try yourself:)

Comment: Is it possible to increase the size of this icon?

Comment: Is it possible to override this blue dot icon with my custom icon, like uber cars?

Answer (score 0):

In *Kotlin* :

```
        map.isMyLocationEnabled = true
```

**NOT** to be confused with :

<strike>map.uiSettings.isMyLocationButtonEnabled = true</strike>

I've used [it](https://github.com/maifeeulasad/SDAS/blob/208a57bf0f7f190cd027d8e6dc7de61106196eec/mas/app/src/main/java/com/mua/mobileattendance/activity/MapActivity.kt#L194) in my project. And here is the result :

[image: show location with direction google map kotlin android]

For embeded view, check out Page 35, [here](https://github.com/maifeeulasad/CSE618-SDAS/blob/files/CSE%20618%20-%20Smartphone%20based%20Digital%20Attendance%20System.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

In Latest **Flutter 2.0.1 , Dart 2.12.0**
Use below updated method to show **blue dot** on your current Location:

```
myLocationEnabled: true,
```

Answer (score -3):

Write the following -

```
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myLoc, 15));
```

Maximum zoom view can be upto 20.